# Query data from Hana database with R, dealing with quotes

Tags: sql, r, rodbc, hana

I use `R` to read data from a Hana database.  Some of the table names include backslashes, which forces me to use quotation marks.  I cannot read these tables using `R`. Let me show you an example ...

This SQL works in Hana:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM P3O."/BBB/BBB";
```

When I try to use the same code to read the data with R from the Hana database I get these errors:

```
library("RODBC") 
channel <- odbcConnect("xxx",uid="xxx",pwd="xxx") 
query <- 
paste("'","SELECT COUNT(*) FROM P30.", "\"/BBB/BBB\"","'",sep="")
RAW_dataHana   <- sqlQuery(channel, query)  
close(channel)
```

I get following errors:

> Syntax error or access violation;257 sql syntax error: incorrect
>   syntax near \"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... [2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not
>   SQLExecDirect ''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM P30.\"/BBB/BBB\"''"

I think it has something to do with the quotation, but when I check the code with this, I think I get the correct query:

```
x = paste("'","SELECT COUNT(*) FROM P30.", "\"/BBB/BBB\"", "'",sep="")
cat(x) 
> cat(x)
'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM P30."/BBB/BBB"'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just got now to check my RODBC test code...
The easiest way to handle the quoting is to enclose the query string in single quotes, e.g.:

```
sales_fact<-sqlQuery (ch, 'SELECT TOP 200 "ORDERID", "VAR_INDICATOR",
                                        sum("ORDER_CNT") AS "ORDER_CNT",
                                        sum("VARIANCE") AS "VARIANCE",
                                        sum("VARIANCE_PCT") AS "VARIANCE_PCT",
                                        sum("BUDGET") AS "BUDGET",
                                        sum("ACTUAL") AS "ACTUAL"
                          FROM "_SYS_BIC"."test/ODERS_CV"
                          GROUP BY "ORDERID", "VAR_INDICATOR"')
```

This also works with paste():

```
queryText <- 'SELECT TOP 200 "ORDERID", "VAR_INDICATOR",
                                        sum("ORDER_CNT") AS "ORDER_CNT",...'

queryText <- paste(sep = '', queryText, ' "_SYS_BIC"."test/ODERS_CV"
                          GROUP BY "ORDERID", "VAR_INDICATOR"')
```